# Beautiful Soup trying to get information on <code>/<-- comment tag

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am trying to obtain the profile picture of facebook users, via their profile page (if the pictures is available on their public profile)

And I am having difficulties to get it via beautiful soup.

For now I am finding the location of the picture link with this code below:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

page_open = br.open("https://www.facebook.com/zuck")

x= soup.find(id="u_0_6") #change sometime with "u_0_5"
strx = str(x)
strx[2469:2690]  #really bad choice
```

From that last line i can extract the url only if the previous code didn't change and it never happen.
How can I obtain the data

```
"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c14.4.153.153/1939620_10101266232851011_437577509_n.jpg?oh=014037065b8baa2346444c66b16ddc25&oe=5547259F&__gda__=1429976114_ffd73e14776a391219e64a1ce6a4d1fb"
```

That is located in this part of html:

```
<code class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_6"><!-- <div class="timelineLoggedOutSignUp"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up" data-referrer="pagelet_loggedout_sign_up"></div></div><div class="fbTimelineTopSectionBase _6-d _529n"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_above_header_timeline" data-referrer="pagelet_above_header_timeline"></div><div id="above_header_timeline_placeholder"></div><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineTopSection fbTimelineLoggedOutTopSection"><div id="fbProfileCover"><div class="cover" id="u_0_2"><a class="coverWrap coverImage" href="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10101026493146301&amp;set=a.941146602501.2418915.4&amp;type=1" rel="theater" ajaxify="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10101026493146301&amp;set=a.941146602501.2418915.4&amp;type=1&amp;src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-frc3%2Ft31.0-8%2F1275272_10101026493146301_791186452_o.jpg&amp;smallsrc=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-xap1%2Fv%2Ft1.0-9%2F1186268_10101026493146301_791186452_n.jpg%3Foh%3Dfc0981d4a65c2e984cf5c43fdc1bcc88%26oe%3D55072936%26__gda__%3D1430325870_8783e46096a8a5456fc0e745fb89f303&amp;size=1434%2C717&amp;source=10&amp;player_origin=profile" title="Photo de couverture" id="fbCoverImageContainer" data-cropped="1"><img class="coverPhotoImg photo img" src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t31.0-8/q83/c0.93.1434.531/s851x315/1275272_10101026493146301_791186452_o.jpg" style="top:0px;width:100%" data-fbid="10101026493146301" alt="Photo de couverture" /><div class="coverBorder"></div><img class="coverChangeThrobber img" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yk/r/LOOn0JtHNzb.gif" alt="" width="16" height="16" /></a></div><div id="fbTimelineHeadline" class="clearfix"><div class="actions"><div class="_5h60 actionsDropdown" id="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions" data-referrer="pagelet_timeline_profile_actions"></div></div><div class="name"><div class="photoContainer"><div><div class="profilePicThumb"><img class="profilePic img" alt="Mark Zuckerberg" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c14.4.153.153/1939620_10101266232851011_437577509_n.jpg?oh=014037065b8baa2346444c66b16ddc25&amp;oe=5547259F&amp;__gda__=1429976114_ffd73e14776a391219e64a1ce6a4d1fb" /></div></div><meta itemprop="image" content="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c14.4.153.153/s50x50/1939620_10101266232851011_437577509_n.jpg?oh=6b6cd8460210e1de160cf8a6056df416&amp;oe=550D5F6C&amp;__gda__=1429858477_b29a956770b6173d71cb28eb35fa99e6" /></div><h2 itemprop="name">Mark Zuckerberg<span data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-position="right" class="_56_f _5dzy _5d-1" id="u_0_4"></span></h2></div></div></div></div></div><div class="timelineLoggedOutPagelet"><div class="clearfix"><div class="timelineLoggedOutMain lfloat _ohe"><div class="_5h60 allFavorites" id="pagelet_all_favorites" data-referrer="pagelet_all_favorites"></div></div><div class="timelineLoggedOutRight rfloat _ohf"><div class="fbTimelineSection mtm fbTimelineCompactSection"><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_search" data-referrer="pagelet_search"></div></div><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_people_same_name" data-referrer="pagelet_people_same_name"></div><div class="_5h60" id="pagelet_contact" data-referrer="pagelet_contact"></div></div></div></div> --></code>
```

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed according Facebook Scraping policy: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php

Comment: Correct - plus you would need authentification btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or instead of scraping Facebook, you can do it the proper way - through their graph API ;)

```
import requests

url = "http://graph.facebook.com/{}".format("zuck")
params = { "fields": "picture" }
response = requests.get(url, params=params).json()

picture_url = response['picture']['data']['url']
print(picture_url)

# output:
# https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c14.4.153.153/s50x50/1939620_10101266232851011_437577509_n.jpg?oh=6b6cd8460210e1de160cf8a6056df416&oe=550D5F6C&__gda__=1429858477_b29a956770b6173d71cb28eb35fa99e6
```

Explanation: profile picture url is a public field - you can access it without authentification.

**Advantages:**

1. You don't even have to use BeautifulSoup
2. The response is much faster
3. You do it *the developer's way* (as opposed to the dirty hacker's way)
4. You're using `requests` which is MUCH more practical than `url lib`

To play around with Facebook graph api: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Thank you, I though graph API was only when the user log in your app and you will be able to access but since it is public field I understand now! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how reliable this is, because `<code><!-- <div...` looks very odd to me with my limited knowledge of HTML, but this snippet should work:

```
element= soup.find(id="u_0_6")
soup= BeautifulSoup(element.string)
image= soup.find('img', attrs={'class': ['profilePic']})
print image
```

Comment: Thank, I tried unfortunatly didn't work, I choose Jivan answer for the advantages listed by himself :) thank you !